# Error converting data type varchar to float on populating GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am populating the GridView with following code on basis of Numeric data put in the textbox and clicking the button.
But it is giving the following error.
Error converting data type varchar to float. 
As my database column 'matri_perct' has datatype 'float'.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL Connection String"].ConnectionString);con.Open();
        com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM stdtable WHERE matri_perct >  @Percent", con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Percent", float.Parse(txtPercent.Text));
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Data");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataMember = "Data";
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception err)
        {
            Label1.Text = err.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

My GridView .aspx code is declared as

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="univ_regno" DataSourceID="" EnableModelValidation="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="school" HeaderText="School" 
            SortExpression="school" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="univ_regno" HeaderText="Univ R.No." ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="univ_regno" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="colge_rollno" HeaderText="Coll. R.No." 
            SortExpression="colge_rollno" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="branch" HeaderText="Branch" 
            SortExpression="branch" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sem" HeaderText="Sem" SortExpression="sem" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="f_name" HeaderText="F.Name" 
            SortExpression="f_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date_birth" HeaderText="DOB" 
            SortExpression="date_birth" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="mob" HeaderText="Mobile" 
            SortExpression="mob" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="E-mail" SortExpression="email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="matri_perct" HeaderText="Matric %" 
            SortExpression="matri_perct" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intermed_perct" HeaderText="Intermediate %" 
            SortExpression="intermed_perct" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="grad_perct" HeaderText="UG %" 
            SortExpression="grad_perct" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="post_grad_perct" HeaderText="PG %" 
            SortExpression="post_grad_perct" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="other_perct" HeaderText="Other %" 
            SortExpression="other_perct" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="no_backlogs" HeaderText="Backlogs" 
            SortExpression="no_backlogs" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" 
            SortExpression="Password" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="studentprofile" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SQL Connection String %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [school], [univ_regno], [colge_rollno], [branch], [sem], [name], [f_name], [date_birth], [cores_add], [mob], [email], [matri_perct], [intermed_perct], [grad_perct], [post_grad_perct], [other_perct], [no_backlogs], [Password] FROM [stdtable] ORDER BY [branch], [univ_regno]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: i have removed the DataSouceID from original code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my question with the help of @Bob Kaufman & @rene
The complete solution of my question is following:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL Connection String"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM stdtable WHERE matri_perct >  @Percent", con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percent", float.Parse(txtPercent.Text));
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();  // execute SELECT statement, store result in data reader
        GridView1.DataSource = reader;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
         }
    catch (System.Exception err)
    {
        Label1.Text = err.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

And then i have changed the AllowPaging=false

It works ;)

Answer (score 3):

First, get into the habit of constructing SQL statements using [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx), like in rene's answer, rather than through concatenation. You'll avoid a lot of problems (e.g., SQL injection attacks, strings with escape characters that break a SQL statement) this way.

Second, if `matri_perct` is a float, the correct syntax would be:

```
com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM stdtable WHERE matri_perct > " + 
    float.Parse(txtPercent.Text) + ", con);
```

without the singlequotes or percent signs.

As I've said, **don't copy this directly into your production code!**, rather convert the user input into a parameter. Consider what would happen if a [user](http://xkcd.com/327/) entered

```
0); DROP TABLE Students; --
```

into your textbox.

**EDIT**

This code is a little confusing to me:

```
com.ExecuteNonQuery();  // looks like you're running the SELECT statement then discarding the result
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Data");  // I don't see how this gets the data from your query, above.
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataMember = "Data";  // see my change, below.
```

How about this instead (leave your first three lines intact):

```
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();  // execute SELECT statement, store result in data reader
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.Fill( reader );
GridView1.DataSource = adapter;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I have edited updated code as @rene answered. Now it is saying 'The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.'

Comment: Changed code according to you Now error is Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.

Comment: Now The data source does not support server-side data paging.

Comment: Turns out that you do need a SqlDataAdapter to support paging, but I don't think you were initializing it correctly. See the edit I've made above. It's been a while since I've used these. Regrettably we're starting to get to the end of my knowledge on this matter.

Comment: Please see the last edit now. Thanks for your co operation till now..:)

Answer (score 2):

Let the sqlclient do the heavy lifting:

```
    com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM stdtable WHERE matri_perct >  @percent", con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("percent", float.Parse(txtPercent.Text));
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or if you want to be more specific about the [sqlparameter type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx):

```
com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM stdtable WHERE matri_perct >  @percent", con);
var percentParam = new SqlParameter("percent", SqlDbType.Float);
percentParam.Value = txtPercent.Text;
com.Parameters.Add(percentParam);
```

Most importantly: Always use parameters (as pointed out by Bob) instead of string concatenation or you will find trouble along the way.